# Wordpress pending review

Tags: wordpress

What I want to do sounds simple .

I will publish a page. At a later date I will update the content - add extra material. And set it to “pending review”. However I would like the previous published version, if there is one, to still display on the live site for non logged in users and not get a page not found error..

Is it possible? How can I do this?

Comment: if you set to pending review, it wont display in front end

Comment: Yes I know that. I was hoping there was a way to show the previous version - before the edit in the front end.